# Angular save modified data from one table to another

Tags: angular

I need advice about angular change strategy.
I have PatientData and ChangeLog table.

PatientData table

```
    {
      name: "John",
      price: 10,
      ...
    }
```

If I change I price from 10 to 15 I need copy "PatienData" data to
my new "ChangeLog" table and show name + modified and old price

Example of ChangeLog table

```
    {
       name: "John",
       changes:
       [
          oldPrice: 10,
          newPrice: 15
       ]
     }
```

P.S. I have 2 components. First one I use for saving data to my PatientData
table , second one I need to use saving modified data to my ChangeLog table
also showing previous and current Value.

Comment: So what is your question ?

Comment: Which strategy I need to use for showing previous and current price when I save data to my ChangeLog table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store the data and also show the changed data in a different component on event change,

> 1. Have a service ready to store the data and use it in different component.
> 2. Update the binding object to the new value, something like shown below.

```
changedData.oldData = !!changedData.oldData ? changedData.newData : svcVariable;
changedData.newData = svcVariable
```

> 3. Insert the data into the db.

If you have not come across component to component communication in angular, you can read about it.
One of the article I found is https://medium.com/@mirokoczka/3-ways-to-communicate-between-angular-components-a1e3f3304ecb

Hope this helps! Happy Coding!